# Access HP Switch Web-UI in HTTPS Admin Mode

Tags: windows, security, certificate, https, trusted-root-certificates

On my *HP 1820 G24 Switch*, I set *Secure HTTP Configuration* (enabled *HTTPS Admin Mode*). For that, the Switch generated its own SSL certificate.

So far so good.

--

When I try to access the Web-UI in HTTPS Admin Mode, I get this:

[image]

(When I click the link in the yellow area above) In 'advanced', I proceed:

[image]

(When I click the link in the yellow area above) The certificate dialog:

[image]

When I 'Log In' to the Switch, I see in the Log: "HTTPS Session 33 started for user Amit G. connected from 192.168.1.190".

--

**What is the "best approach" (security wise) to deal with that "Not secure" warning?** (To install the certificate? How do I get it from the Switch? To leave it "as is" is an option too).